# how to know when is azure blob storage snapshot promotion is done

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Azure blob client has these 2 methods to promote a snapshot. From the description, both indicate that the function will return once the promotion process is **started** as opposed to **completed**. I wonder if my understanding is correct? If so, how do we know when the promotion is actually done, i.e the blob is restored to the content of snapshot.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.startcopy?view=azure-dotnet

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.startcopyasync?view=azure-dotnet

Answer (score 0):

Even though blob copy operation is asynchronous, when a blob is copied in the same account (either same container or different), it is actually a synchronous operation and the copy happens instantly.

Assuming you're promoting a snapshot and overwriting the base blob with a snapshot, since the copy operation is happening in the same storage account, it will be done as soon as the copy operation returns you an acknowledgement.

If you're taking a blob snapshot and copying it in a different account, then the operation will be asynchronous. In that case, you can fetch blob properties using [`FetchAttributes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblob.fetchattributes?view=azure-dotnet) method and check blob's [`Copy Properties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblob.copystate?view=azure-dotnet). That will tell you when the copy operation has completed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For "it will be done as soon as the copy operation returns you an acknowledgement", I wonder if you know if there is any documentation to confirm this behavior?

Comment: I created a simple program to take snapshot and revert to a snapshot for 1,2,4,8,16Kb, 400Mb file. For each file size, I do 100 iterations and here are the average time in ms:
(avg take snap, revert, in ms)
1kb:30,51 
2kb:30,47
4kb:30,47
8kb:33,44
16kb:31,29
400Mb:27,45

From the number, we can see there is no relationship between the time used and the file size. Logically, I would assume taking a snapshot of a bigger file takes longer time?

Comment: Unfortunately I could not find any documentation reference about the synchronous comment. This is what I have observed working with copy blobs functionality.